# A short hyphen in a math formula

Tags: math-mode, symbols, lyx, hyphenation

In a LyX math formula, I want to write something like "r-number". However, the usual dash looks too long (like a minus sign). I am looking for a short, possibly upper hyphen. I couldn't find it in the lists of symbols in the bottom toolbar, and I also don't know how to search for symbols online If you can give me a tip, how to find a symbol that I need, this will be very useful.

Comment: Can't we use `\text{r-number}` with package `amstext` loaded? I haven't used LyX though. Also check the symbols list at http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf.

Comment: Here's what I use for "F-an" (meaning F-analytic) \text{$F\!\mbox{-}\mathrm{an}$}

Comment: The right way to type this is `$r$-number`: only the $r$ is part of the formula; or else do you need the whole "r-number" inside a formula?

Comment: I need all of it inside the formula. It is the name of a function.

Comment: @LaurentBerger, that seems like an awful lot of work to subvert LaTeX's understanding of what is math and what is text.  Why not `\text{$F$-an}`?

Comment: The `unicode-math` package knows `\mathhyphen`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here are three suggestions. The first is my own, and the second and third are adapted from (http://www.logic.at/staff/salzer/etc/mhyphen/). Note that the first and second both output "math italic" text, but the third outputs "upright" text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\rnumber{\mathop{\mbox{$r$-$\mathit{number}$}}}
\[
\rnumber(5) = 120
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\mathchardef\mhyphen="2D % Define a "math hyphen"
\begin{document}
\newcommand\rnumber{\mathop{r\mhyphen number}}
\[
\rnumber(5) = 120
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\rnumber{\operatorname{r-number}}
\[
\rnumber(5) = 120
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

LyX users should put the definitions (`\usepackage`, `\newcommand`, `\mathchardef`, etc.) in Document -> Settings -> LaTeX Preamble, and the usage (e.g. `\rnumber(5) = 120`) inside math-mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you! I edited to add a note for LyX users (such as myself).

Comment: what is "2D? Is that the character definition for hyphen? if so, where can I find others?

Comment: @nlucaroni, it is just the ASCII code in hexadecimal:  see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart

Comment: You should move the `\newcommand`s to the document preamble (before `\begin{document}`).

Comment: This is incredibly useful, thank you. I only needed `\mbox{\texttt{+-+-+-}}`.

Answer (score 58):

I think this is simpler.

```
$r{\text -}number(5)=120$
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Here some helpful information [How do I write a good answer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Best answer here.

Comment: The braces serve no purpose, `\text` already makes an ord atom. (The "proper LaTeX" usage would be `\text{-}`, but TeX does not really care if you put single-letter macro arguments in braces. In fact, the space is also redundant, it can be just `\text-`.) And it should be `\mathit{number}` to make kerning correct.

Answer (score 14):

My first shot would be `\DeclareMathOperator`; but it depends on the meaning of "r": if it represents a math variable it should be in italics. I'll show both possibilities, take your pick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\rnumberA}{r-number}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rnumberB}{\mathnormal{r}-number}

\begin{document}

$\rnumberA(2)$

$\rnumberB(2)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that this solution does not work to typeset an r'-number: the ' becomes an apostrophe, rather than a prime.

Comment: @Bubaya You can use `r^{\prime}`.

Comment: Sure, but how about `\operatorname{\mathnormal{r^2}-number}`?

Comment: @Bubaya `\mathnormal{r}^2`

Comment: Sorry, my comment was apparently too short to make my point. If I write `\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\operatorname{\mathnormal{#1}-Mod}}`, things like `\Mod{A_2}` fail.

Comment: @Bubaya You're not defining an operator to begin with: `\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{#1{\operatorname{-Mod}}}` is the way to go. For right modules, `\newcommand{\rMod}[1]{{\operatorname{Mod-}}#1}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115614/discussion-between-bubaya-and-egreg).

Answer (score 10):

To define a hyphen for use as part of a hyphenated name in a macro, I used the command `\def\mymathhyphen{{\hbox{-}}}`.  This gives the usual en-dash.

Answer (score 4):

Another beautiful dash defined as a symbol.
Short and simple.

```
\documentclass{article}

%Defining my short hyphen with name \mhyphen
%as an ordinary (\mathord) math symbol.
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mhyphen}{\mathord}{AMSa}{"39}

\begin{document}
$r\mhyphen number(t)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Advantages:

- No extra packages needed.
- No need to change from math to text mode.
- The whole expression *r-number(t)* needs not be redefined as operator, i.e., `\mathop` or similars. It affects spacing in formulae.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way to create a dash is to use a strike-out through a space.

It creates a slightly longer one than given in the answer by Sam Buss, which is what I needed. One could define the macro by

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\mydash}{\hbox{\sout{ }}}
```